# Get file path & filename with asp:FileUpload, don't want file... just path and name

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, .net

I am developing a .NET intranet site which will enable the user to see a list of files (file details stored in DB) and link to the actual PDF/XML/XLS and open it... kind of like a table of contents for the network.

During data entry, the user enters various data about a document, then browses to the file on the network and selects it using the asp:FileUpload.  The codebehind then saves the network path to the DB.  There is alot of overhead here because i'm sending the file to the server but never use it.

Everything has been working fine until someone tries to use a large PDF file then I get the dreaded MAXIMUM REQUEST LENGTH EXCEEDED error... So I'm trying to find a solution here...  I do not need the actual file.. just the path and filename.

I know not all browsers send the full path but our systems have older browsers so everything is working fine now, but will probably break soon.. which is another reason to find a different solution.

I've looked into Javascript to pull the path but that won't work...

Any other ideas?  Other ways to just grab the path and filename? (besides manually typing it in to a Text field)

Thanks,
Todd.

Answer (score 1):

```
This may help too
```

[How to get the full path of a file from asp: file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511570/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-a-file-from-asp-file-upload)

string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);//file name
string path= Server.MapPath(filename);//path